# Prepared PHP SQL statement returns false without GROUP BY clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a prepared statement:

```
if ( $statement = $this->connection->prepare("SELECT question_type, count(*) AS `count` FROM (SELECT question.*, left(question_body, locate('between', question_body)-2) AS question_type FROM question) q WHERE (q.question_type = ? AND q.response_value_id = ?)") ) {
    $statement->bind_param("si", $question_type, $response_value_id);
    $statement->execute();
    return $statement->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
} else {
    var_dump($this->db->error);
}
```

Here is the query:

```
SELECT question_type, count(*) AS `count` FROM 
(SELECT question.*, left(question_body, locate('between', question_body) - 2) 
AS question_type FROM question) 
q WHERE q.question_type = 'Did you return home' AND q.response_value_id = 4
```

The problem: 
For some reason the prepared statement is returning false although I have tried to run the query on phpMyAdmin and it works perfectly.
If I execute the prepared statement without a guard for an error, I get the error: `bind_param() on boolean`.

If I add to the end of my query:

```
GROUP BY q.question_type
```

Then everything works. However, that is not what I want since it returns null for the counts instead of 0, and I also do not understand how it is not working without the GROUP BY.

Comment: if you want a count by question_type you need to add GROUP BY q.question_type. Otherwise take out  question_type  before count(*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of aggregation function without group by is depracted  and in the most recent version of mysql (5.7) is not allowed 
Check for you right versione and anyway try use ever agregated  function for column not mentioned in group by 
eg :

```
  "SELECT question_type, count(*) AS `count` 
    FROM (
      SELECT question.*, left(question_body, locate('between', question_body)-2) AS question_type 
      FROM question ) q 
  WHERE q.question_type = ? AND q.response_value_id = ?
  GROUP BY question_type)"
```

or

```
  "SELECT min(question_type), count(*) AS `count` 
    FROM (
      SELECT question.*, left(question_body, locate('between', question_body)-2) AS question_type 
      FROM question ) q 
  WHERE (q.question_type = ? AND q.response_value_id = ?)"
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, this makes so much sense. It explains why everything works in my desktop (older version of sql) but I have been running into problems in the the newest version. The first answer that you give returns syntax error on line 6, could you edit that? I tried separating the BY question_type and it didn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you want a count by question_type you need to add GROUP BY q.question_type. Otherwise take out question_type before count(*) in your select statement. try this:

```
SELECT count(*) AS `count` FROM 
(SELECT question.*, left(question_body, locate('between', question_body)-2) 
AS question_type FROM question) 
q WHERE q.question_type = 'Did you return home' AND q.response_value_id = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever using aggregation functions in addition to displaying other fields (in your example question_type) you **must** use GROUP BY.

You could use [ISNULL](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwio8a_Qu7vVAhXBzRoKHUOoB24QFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fsql%2Fsql_isnull.asp&usg=AFQjCNFrWct5wfXgdTwwpNIRe6TAusnVTQ) on the field you're counting while using GROUP BY.